# Accumulating (concatenate) values in variable does not work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to accumulate values into a variable in SQL Server>=2012.

It works in case 1 below, but in case 2 I get the answer ",CD" instead of the expected ",EF,AB,CD" Why?

In MMS:

```
USE MyDB
GO

-- Create a simple table
CREATE TABLE Tbl1 (Code VARCHAR(2), So TINYINT NULL)
INSERT INTO Tbl1 VALUES('AB', 10)
INSERT INTO Tbl1 VALUES('CD', NULL)
INSERT INTO Tbl1 VALUES('EF', 5)
GO

-- Case 1
DECLARE @MyVar VARCHAR(255) = ''
SELECT @MyVar=@MyVar + ',' + Code FROM Tbl1 ORDER BY So
SELECT @MyVar
GO

-- Case 2
DECLARE @MyVar VARCHAR(255) = ''
SELECT @MyVar=@MyVar + ',' + Code FROM Tbl1 ORDER BY ISNULL(So, 255)
SELECT @MyVar
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks):

> Don't use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that
> is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur.
> Because, all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments)
> aren't necessarily run exactly once for each output row.

There are opinions (but not in the official docs), stating that without an `ORDER BY` clause (and/or a `DISTINCT` clause) the aggregation works as you expect.

If you are using SQL Server 2017+, you may use `STRING_AGG()` to build the expected output:

```
DECLARE @MyVar VARCHAR(255) = ''
SELECT @MyVar = STRING_AGG(Code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ISNULL(So, 255))
FROM Tbl1 
SELECT @MyVar
```